# how to update a table and return all table items without using find method in spring jpa

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How can one update a table and return all table items without using find method in spring jpa?

Example:

```
    //InetAddress ipAddr = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
    Purchase p = new Purchase();
    //p.setDatebuy(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
    p.setPurchase_id(post.getPurchase_id());
    p.setUserid(post.getUserid());
    p.setType_payment(post.getType_payment());
    p.setActive(post.getActive());
    //p.setIp(ipAddr.getHostAddress());
    Purchase ps = purchaseRepository.save(p);

logger.info(ps.getIp()+">>"+ps.getDatebuy());
```

Comment: Do it in raw sql, like two queries?

Comment: I'm using CQRS and I can't use queries, do you know another solution? thanks.

Comment: how does CQRS restrict you from using queries? Is it because this is the command part? But then any read from the database, either via raw SQL or any abstraction on top of it would be a query anyway.

Comment: I solved it using mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query,update,CartPurchaseMongo.class); thank you